# How to get formControlName Programmatically in Angular 5 or above

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

Need to know, when you have a multiple controls in a form and you want to know to which control user changed so that you can take some actions.

```
<input formControlName="item_name" #itemName (input)="inputChanged(itemName)">
```

**Why I need to get formControlName?**

as you can see in the image, some fields are edited but not confirmed that's why user sees options to verify or cancel the operation on that specific field. That's why I require to get `formControlName` of input-changed field so that I can display the options only to that field.

[image]

I have searched for its solution but couldn't found on `stack-overflow` that's why I decided to post this question with answer

Comment: Why can't you just pass the name as a string to `inputChanged("item_name")`?

Comment: When you have a multiple controls and you want to get the control name that input has been changed.

Comment: Why would you need (input) at all with controls? Their purpose is to avoid things like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

from this input field to get `formControlName`

```
<input formControlName="item_name" #itemName (input)="inputChanged(itemName)">
```

You only need to get the attribute `formControlName`

```
inputChanged(element: HTMLElement) {
  log(element.getAttribute('formControlName')) // item_name 
}
```

Comment: Using a template reference variable is the simplest solution to match the simple src event html technic.
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars

Comment: Note: Be aware that you will not have a `formControlName` attribute, when you set the `formControlName` as template variable, e.g. `[formControlName]="xyz"`. Did cost me some time and headache to figure that out.

Answer (score 5):

Most straighforward way I've found:

HTML:

```
<input formControlName="item_name" (input)="inputChanged($event)">
```

TS:

```
inputChanged(e) {
  log(e.target.getAttribute('formControlName')) // item_name 
}
```

No need to add an `id` in every input. Just pass `$event` as parameter.

Comment: Not sure if its a question of Angular Version. I'm using Angular 9.2. I cannot find an attribute  `formControlName`, but there is an attribute `ng-reflect-name`, which seems to be set to the `fromControlName`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use that approach:

```
<input formControlName="item_name" #itemName (change)="inputChanged($event)">
```

When the input's value changes, the change event occurs, and Angular provides a corresponding DOM event object in the $event variable which this code passes as a parameter to the component's inputChanged() method.

```
inputChanged (event: any) { // without type info
this.myValue = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

Reference link:
https://angular.io/guide/user-input

## Another alternative more elegant:

#### template

```
<form [formGroup]="usersForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="name"/>
</form>
```

#### component class

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  usersForm: FormGroup;
  message: string;

  private subscriptions$ = new Subscription();

  constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.usersForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: '',
      age: '',
      gender: '',
    });

    this.subscriptions$.add(this.name.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      // Do someting
    }));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions$.unsubscribe();
  }

  get name(): AbstractControl {
    return this.usersForm.get('name');
  }
}
```

See the complete example in the Stackbliz: 
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-builder-example](https://angular.io/guide/user-input)

Comment: I want to get the formControlName. Is there any way to get in function "inputChanged" ?

Comment: if you see, I am using the "valueChanges" Observable from the "AbstractControl" class. This Observable returns the Value;

Comment: With this approach you know exactly which control has changed.

Answer (score 1):

If You are using Reactive Forms then instead of declaring **formControlName** in component template, you can create form in **Component TS** as follows:

```
 this.myForm= this.formBuilder.group({
      'item_name' : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
```

Also, Instead of handling input changes through event, Reactive forms provide you privilege to handle input value changes by registering "**value_changes**" upon form field as follows:

```
this.myForm.get('item_name').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    this.formattedMessage = `My name is ${val}.`;
  });
```

In this way you always use the **formControlName** as defined in Reactive form Group in Component TS Definition.

It will be used in component template as follows:

```
<input formControlName="item_name" />
```

Comment: your method looks good to me. Can you share a detailed document or video link please.

Comment: Yes you can find detailed documentation in following link: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 1):

You can get formControlName attribute using ElementRef

**HTML Code**

```
 <input formControlName="item_name" #itemName>
```

**component Class file**

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 

    // itemName name is reference variable #itemName

    @ViewChild('itemName') itemName: ElementRef;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.itemName.nativeElement.getAttribute('formControlName');
    }
}
```

**Get Change Value of formControllName**

```
<input type="text" formControlName="item_name" #itemName (input)="inputChanged($event.target.value)">

   export class AppComponent {
    inputChanged(searchValue: string) {
    console.log(searchValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular Reactive Forms you can use something like this

For you HTML input

```
<input formControlName="item_name" #itemName (change)="inputChanged()">
```

For you component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

formName: FormGroup;
myValue: string;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.formName = this.formBuilder.group({
      'item_name' : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });

    window.scroll(0,0);
}

inputChanged(){
    this.myValue = this.formName.get('item_name').value;
}
```

Reference link:
https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 0):

Reactive form instances like FormGroup and FormControl have a valueChanges method that returns an observable that emits the latest values. You can therefore subscribe to valueChanges to update instance variables or perform operations.

Example

```
myForm: FormGroup;
formattedMessage: string;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    message: ''
  });

  this.onChanges();
}
```

Notice how we call an onChanges method in the ngOnInit lifecycle hook after having initialized our form. Here’s the content of our onChanges method:

```
onChanges(): void {
  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    this.formattedMessage =
    `Hello,

    My name is ${val.name} and my email is ${val.email}.

    I would like to tell you that ${val.message}.`;
  });
}
```

You can also listen for changes on specific form controls instead of the whole form group:

```
onChanges(): void {
  this.myForm.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    this.formattedMessage = `My name is ${val}.`;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the formControlName from the input dynamically , one option is to use the event from the function in HTML

```
<input formControlName="item_name" #itemName (input)="inputChanged($event)">
```

and from component

```
inputChanged(event) {
   console.log(event.srcElement.attributes.formcontrolname.value); //prints item_name
}
```